# Make image transparent in CSS

Tags: css, image, transparency

So here is my code, it works fine, but I want the image to be 50% transparent.

```
 #esc1{ 
 position: absolute; 
 top:30px; 
 right: 0; 
 width: 30px; 
 height: 30px;
 }
```

So sorry, I posted the wrong code before..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set opacity to your class for which you want to give transparency.

eg :

```
#esc1 {
 position: absolute; 
 top:30px; 
 right: 0; 
 width: 30px; 
 height: 30px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

you can give opacity with background, too

eg : `background : rgba(red_value , green_value , blue_value, alpha_value);`

**red_value, green_value , blue_value**  are the combined value for your div background-color. and **alpha_value** is the opacity value to your div.

Set opacity according to your need.

**Note** :  its value should be between **0** to **1** including **0** and **1**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

for  transparent background

```
 #esc1{ 
 position: absolute; 
 top:30px; 
 right: 0; 
 width: 30px; 
 height: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
 }
```

for  transparent element

```
 #esc1{ 
 position: absolute; 
 top:30px; 
 right: 0; 
 width: 30px; 
 height: 30px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the opacity property

.myClass {
    opacity: 0.5
}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to achieve this and it is hard to tell which one would be best without looking at your code but one way to do this is through opacity like follow:

```
opacity: .5
```

Where .5 is the amount of transparency. .5 is equivalent to 50% transparency.

or If it is background color then you can use:

```
background-color: rgba(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaVale);
```

Alpha value varies same as opacity from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

all image in single-testimonial class transparent in CSS :)

```
        <style>
 .single-testimonial img{
        opacity: 0.8!important;
    }
</style>
    <div class="single-testimonial">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <img src="b-2.jpg" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h2>Louis Smith</h2>
                                            <p>
                                           برنامه نویسان مریخی
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```